# Getting array of images in UIImageView (in UIPageViewController)

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, uipageviewcontroller

I've started from the standard PageView-based application template provided by Apple. Now instead of text I want the pages in the app to display images. An array is created as follows:

```
 _pageData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                 nil];
```

This array is handled the following way:

```
DataViewController *dataViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DataViewController"];
dataViewController.dataObject = [self.pageData objectAtIndex:index];
return dataViewController;
```

Then, in DataViewController.h:

```
@interface DataViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *dataObject;
```

And in DataViewController.m I'm trying to display the images in de imageView in the following way:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
  {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_dataObject];

    NSLog(@"dataObject %@", _dataObject);

  }
```

However, with this code I'm not succeeding in getting the images onto the PageViewController. Any idea how I could get this working properly?

A big thanks for you help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here

> ```
> self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_dataObject];
> ```

you are creating a new UIImageView that is dangling arround unused, invisible and without a parent.
You need to set it's size somehow and put it to a parent view with a

```
[<parent> addSubview:self.imageView]
```

to show it.

If your original UIImageView is read from a resource file ( I assume so because it is a IBOutlet ),
just do a

```
self.imageView.image = _dataObject
```

and this should do the job instead.

Comment: Which variant do you use now?
The one at the top might create a lot of UIImageViews and is good for understanding the issue - but not as a real implementation.

Comment: Using the latter:

     self.imageView.image = _dataObject

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
 NSArray *anArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"transparente.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"21001.jpg"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"21002.jpg"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"21003.jpg"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"21004.jpg"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"transparente2.png"],
                        nil];

    _pageData = [anArray copy];
```

and in the dataViewController

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
self.pageImage.image = self.dataObject;
}
```

The pageImage is an UIImageView with an IBOutlet.